# Fixed header in primeng DataTable

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG `4.1.0-rc.2`.

What I'm trying to create is datatable with fixed header. Header should be always visible even if I scroll my table to the bottom (like fixed menu on the top of stackoverflow).

I tried `scrollable` and `scrollHeight` properties of `p-dataTable` but there is a scroll on the table side. I don't need it because I already have one for entire page.
Also I tried to fix it with `position: fixed` but then table headers and table contents have a different size.

Any help would be appreciated.

Now I have something like this: http://embed.plnkr.co/bnB2ZDvDPZos3JLMmVFe/
There is `scrollable` option turned on and `position: fixed` is commented out.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you share code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution, I should use `position: sticky` with `scrollable`.
Here is an example: http://embed.plnkr.co/jZJ3it0ARLLYSe0zI6DL/

Maybe this will help anyone.

EDIT:
Finally there is another solution. In the component:

```
private isScrolled: boolean = false;
constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {
    window.onscroll = () => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
             var header = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-datatable-scrollable-header')[0];
             this.isScrolled = window.pageYOffset > 35; // there is another sticky on the top in my app
             this.renderer.setElementClass(header, 'header_scrolled', this.isScrolled);
        });
    }
}
```

And CSS:

```
.header_scrolled {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 60px; 
}
```

Comment: currently when both scroll and column toggling is enabled datatable headers are not behaving  correctly (alignment issues), can the solution suggested here be used as solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the code bellow into your @Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css'],
  styles: [`
  :host ::ng-deep .ui-table .stk {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0px;
      z-index: 9999;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .margTop {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 52px;
    z-index: 9999;
  }

`],
```

My HTML header is like this:

```
<tr>
                <th class="stk" rowspan="2" style="width:60px;">Field.</th>
                <th class="stk" rowspan="2" style="width:200px;">Field</th>
                <th class="stk" rowspan="2" style="width:135px;">Field</th>
                <th class="stk" rowspan="2" style="width:105px;">Field</th>
                <th class="stk" rowspan="2">Field</th>
                <th class="stk" rowspan="2" style="width:105px;">Field</th>
                <th class="stk" colspan="2"><p class="text-center">Field</p></th>
                <th class="stk" colspan="2"><p class="text-center">Field</p></th>
                <th class="stk" rowspan="2">Field</th>
                <th class="stk" rowspan="2">Field</th>
                <th class="stk" rowspan="2" style="width:60px;">Field</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="margTop">Field</th>
                <th class="margTop">Field</th>
                <th class="margTop">Field</th>
                <th class="margTop">Field</th>
            </tr>
```